# Is my intuition on why the denominator of the root mean square is raised to the power of 1/2 correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I've been going through some threads (see links below) and also a lot of introductory statistics textbooks to try to understand why in the formula for the root mean square, the denominator is also elevated to the power of 1/2. Put more tersely, I've been trying to understand why $\frac{\sqrt {v_1 + v_2+ \cdots+v_n}}{\sqrt n}$ instead of $\frac{\sqrt {v_1 + v_2 +\cdots+v_n}}{n}$ . I finally felt like I had an "Aha!" moment and I would like to know if my "understanding" on this matter is corrrect:

If the denominator were n (and not n to the 1/2), the root mean square would tend to 0 for a big n, even if the denominator were several orders of magnitude smaller than the numerator. By elevating the n to 1/2 we make sure this convergence to 0 doesn't happen, and the only scenario in which the root mean square gets to be 0 is if the numerator is 0.

A very special case that reinforces this idea is an n-dimensional vector whose components are all 1. In this case, the numerator would be n to the 1/2. The only way to make the root mean square equal 1 is if the denominator is also n to the 1/2. If the denominator were n, then the root mean square would be $\frac{\sqrt n}{n}$, which would only make sense if n = 1, and would specially make no sense at all for a very big n, because, as I said in the paragraph above, the root mean square would tend to 0.

Is my intuition correct? Furthermore, could someone recommend me a learning resource (book, video, whatever), that explains this from the intuition to the technical reason?

Thanks so much!

These were the threads I've read:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269405/why-do-we-take-the-square-root-of-variance-to-create-standard-deviation

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64272/why-is-square-root-taken-for-sample-count-n-in-standard-deviation-formula

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116342/why-is-the-standard-deviation-defined-as-sqrt-of-the-variance-and-not-as-the-sqr

Comment: The accepted answer in the third link makes the same argument you did, although without the concrete example where all the data values are equal: namely, as $n$ increases, the formula doesn't converge to the obvious "average" value but instead goes to zero. And there are some other awkward properties mentioned in that answer.

Comment: It's not clear what your purpose here is. Are you looking for a book or video that uses exactly the same argument you did, so that you can feel better about it? What exactly was lacking in the answers that were already given for those three questions?

Comment: My purpose is to verify if I indeed understood the answers in the threads I read. I am new to statistics and much of the technical aspects discussed in them are beyond my current understanding. My question is pretty much: why is the standard deviation defined in textbooks the way it is defined, and usually standard deviation is defined in the first chapter, so I haven't been able to advance much in my understanding. I asked for a book/video/etc recommendation that serves as a good foundational resource to bridge the intuition of statistics with the more technical definitions. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In theory you can make any definitions you please as long as you are clear about it and stick to them. In practice, almost all sets of definitions you could write turn out to be useless or uninteresting (they lead to contradictions, or they never give you any useful insight into anything), so people don't make up definitions like that.

In this case, however, we're not even so much dealing with the definition of a fundamental property (such as "what are parallel lines"),
we are just dealing with a formula that many people have found useful,
and someone has given a name to that formula in order to have a way to conveniently talk about the formula without having to write the entire formula out in detail every time it is mentioned.

There is a classic formula used in probability and statistics that is
typically written
$$\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i= 1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2}{n}},$$

where $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are a list of observations and $\mu$ is the ordinary arithmetic mean of the $x_i$s.
In the case where the $x_i$s are equally likely values of a random variable,
this formula happens to be so useful that it has been given a name: *standard deviation.*

The formula without the square root is also extremely useful, so much so that it also has been given its own name, *variance*:
$${\frac{\sum_{i= 1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2}{n}}.$$

It is also a fact (which you can prove) that
$$
\frac{\sum_{i= 1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2}{n} 
= \left(\frac{\sum_{i= 1}^n x_i^2}{n}\right) - \mu^2.
$$

The term $\left(\sum_{i= 1}^n x_i^2\right)/n$ is itself so useful that it also has a name, *second moment.*
But I cannot recall anyone taking the square root of the second moment of an arbitrary distribution to do anything interesting; it only seems to happen by coincidence when the mean is zero, since the second moment is then equal to the variance.

But if you take the square root of the "numerator" part of the standard deviation formula, and leave the denominator $n$ outside the square root, as in
$$\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i= 1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2}}{n},$$
then (as you observed) strange things happen, such as if you just have more observations of the same value of $(x_i - \mu)^2$ then this "average" ends up smaller, eventually tending toward $0$ as you put together larger and larger lists of identical values of $(x_i - \mu)^2.$
Now, you could prove this formally, but most textbook writers don't like to waste pages proving that the formulas they are **not** going to use in the textbook would give useless results.
You might like to try your own formal proof once you have seen some of the usual proofs of statistical facts, but your intuition is correct and is a perfectly good explanation why we don't have any well-known name for this expression,
whether that name is "standard deviation" or "root mean square" or anything else.

---

The standard deviation (and likewise the variance) is a way to measure how much a random quantity varies from its mean value, but it is hardly the only way.
Another way is
$$
\frac{\sum_{i= 1}^n \lvert x_i - \mu\rvert}{n},
$$
that is, the ordinary arithmetic mean of the absolute values of the differences from the mean. This is a better measurement in some ways, but it is harder to work with.
I do not remember seeing this formula in any introductory statistics book,
but it definitely has a place in statistics; see
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147001/is-minimizing-squared-error-equivalent-to-minimizing-absolute-error-why-squared.

---

I don't recall the words *root mean square* being used much in probability or statistics, but they do come up frequently in other fields such as electrical engineering.
If you pass a current $I$ through a resistor of resistance $R$, the power dissipated in the resistor is $I^2 R.$ If $I$ is in amps and $R$ is in ohms, the power is in watts, meaning the resistor dissipates $I^2R$ joules of energy every second.

So let's say you put the following currents through a resistor of $10$ ohms resistance:

- $I_1 = 2$ amps for $1$ second,
- $I_2 = 3$ amps for $1$ second,
- $I_3 = 2$ amps for $1$ second,
- $I_4 = 1$ amp for $1$ second.

Over the course of $4$ seconds, the amount of energy dissipated (in joules) is

$$ 2^2 \times 10 + 3^2 \times 10 + 2^2 \times 10 + 1^2 \times 10 = 180. $$

In order to dissipate the same amount of energy in $4$ seconds with a constant current through the same resistor, the current has to be
$$ \sqrt{4.5} \approx 2.12132, $$
because that gives you $(\sqrt{4.5})^2 \times 10 = 45$ joules each second, and in $4$ seconds you dissipate $4 \times 45 = 180$ joules. So if power dissipated is the measurement of interest, the electrical engineer computes
$$
\sqrt{\frac{I_1^2 + I_2^2 + I_3^2 + I_4^2}{4}} 
= \sqrt{\frac{2^2 + 3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2}{4}} \approx 2.12132.
$$
But the reason this works (with the division by $4$ inside the square root, not outside) is because the thing inside the square root is the average of $I^2,$
which gives us average power if we multiply by $R.$
And since the electrical engineer is interested in power in this example,
the average power is more useful than the average of anything else.
Hence the desire to know what constant current would dissipate the same average power.

The ordinary arithmetic mean of current doesn't give this answer,
but the "average" computed by the formula above does, so the formula gets used a lot and the electrical engineer would like a convenient name by which to refer to it.
That name is *root mean squared* current.
Why "root mean square"? Because we take the arithmetic mean of the squares, and then take the square root of that; it's an abbreviated way to say "square root of the mean of the squares."

When I do (on rare occasions) see the words "root mean square" during a discussion of statistics, I tend to think the term is borrowed from one of those fields where it is typically used, and that its use in that particular discussion is to remind people that root mean square averages are useful in other fields, so the same formula should not be considered weird and counterintuitive when it is used in probability and statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right.  If the purpose of RMS is to give you some idea of how big your data points are (e.g. how much error there is) then you do not want it to depend merely on the size of the data. In the context of root mean squared error for example, where $v_i$ is the error of a model on the $i$th observation, using the variant formula for an error metric would mean that even if your model is wildly in accurate, the error would go to $0$ as the sample size $n \rightarrow \infty$.

RMS on the other hand does give you some idea of how large your data is.  For example, if $v$ is a nonnegative vector then $\min v \leq RMS(v) \leq \max v$.

More importantly, RMS has a statistical interpretation.  If $X$ is a random variable, then the RMS of draws from $X$ are unbiased estimators of $\sqrt{E(X^2)}$, assuming this is well-defined.  If $X = Y - E(Y)$ for a random variable $Y$, then $\sqrt{E(X^2)}$ is the standard deviation of $Y$, a quantity useful because of its appearance in the formula for the normal distribution; and the normal distribution in turn is important because of the central limit theorem.  The formula with only an $n$ in the denominator cannot have such an interpretation as an estimator of some property of $X$, since as mentioned above its value would depend on the size of the sample.